# Need help converting sql query with pivot to LINQ

Tags: sql-to-linq-conversion

Can someone help me convert the following to LINQ? as I am new to C# and link

SELECT

```
   DayWise, [1] AS Lead1, [2] AS Lead2, [3] AS Lead3, 
   [4] AS Lead4, [5] AS Lead5, [19]   AS Greater
```

FROM (

```
  SELECT   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dt_createdon, 101) AS DayWise, 
  COUNT(int_queryid) AS leadcount ,
  int_queryid 
  FROM tx_searchedresponse       
  GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dt_createdon, 101) ,int_queryid) A  

  PIVOT(     

         COUNT(leadcount)      
         FOR leadcount IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10],       
                        [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19])      
       ) p order by  DayWise
```

Comment: Fix your formatting, it will help readers.